# remove duplicates from Map

Tags: apex

I have a list which contains duplicate entries.

```
List<Account> aList1=new List<Account>([select Id,Name from account where Name LIKE '%Falcon%']);
Map<String,Account> aMap=new Map<String,Account>();
for(Account a:aList1)
{
    aMap.put(a.Name,a); // remove duplicate if any
}
```

Now I have created a trigger on account object that prevents duplicates.

Now I want to compare all values in aMap with all records in aList2.
If there are any duplicates they are removed.

```
List<Account> aList2=[select ID,Name from Account ORDER BY Name];
for(Account a:aList2)
{
   if(aMap.containsKey(a.Name))
       aMap.remove(a.Name);  removes duplicates from aList1
}

Database.Insert(aMap.values(),false);
```

But after the for Loop, aMap is empty.Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, **aMap** and **aList1** are subsets of **aList2**. You are looping through aList2 and removing all the elements in aMap.

The following statement will be true always

> if(aMap.containsKey(a.Name))

And the respective map element will be removed here:

> aMap.remove(a.Name);

At the end of looping, aMap will be empty.

**Update :**

**Scenario: aList1 and aMap are in source org where as aList2 is in destination org.**

Querying for all accounts in destination organization is very inefficient. You'll run into all sorts of limits (SOQL rows, Apex CPU limit etc.,). In destination org, this would be my query:

```
List<Account> aList2=[select ID,Name from Account WHERE Name In :aMap.keySet()];
```

This will give you the already existing accounts that you are trying to insert. Loop through aList2, and remove duplicate elements from aMap.

Comment: Is this an answer or a statement?

Comment: @Eric I was trying to answer why aMap is empty.

Comment: @Avinash, aList1 is a list which is coming from an external salesforce instance (say source) into destination(another salesforce instance) by using rest api. Now I have removed duplicates from aList1. Assuming there could be some duplicates in destination, the objective is too loop through all the records of destination, check if there are duplicates, if there are then remove them and finally do a database.Insert. so while looping through all records of destination, aMap is empty. This is my query.

Comment: I would loop through all records of destination, check if there are any records that are same(duplicate) as those in aMap, if yes then override  those duplicates.I hope I am clear now.

Comment: @DivyaManohar Querying for all accounts in destination organization is very inefficient. You'll run into all sorts of limits (SOQL rows, Apex CPU limit etc.,). In destination org, this would be my query: "List<Account> aList2=[select ID,Name from Account WHERE Name In :aMap.keySet()];" . This will give you the already existing accounts that you are trying to insert. Loop through aList2, and remove duplicate elements from aMap. I think the data set you are testing contains all dupes. That is the reason aMap is coming out as null.

Comment: @Avinash, thanks for expanding my thinking. I was stuck with the idea of comparing all records. I did a mock test of the code u sent and it perfectly worked. Actually I am making an HTTP Callout using a batch apex in source to send records for insert into destination and in destination I am using the same code u said . The batch apex is working but I am unable to insert records into destination. Is it permitted if I make a new post for you to shed light on this?

Comment: @DivyaManohar Yes, that sounds like a different question, create a new one. Can you accept this as the answer? So that others don't try to answer an already answered question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45419/discussion-between-divya-manohar-and-avinash-n).

Answer (score 2):

Maps work on a Key/Value pairs concept where the Key is always unique.  If you your Map already contains a record with a duplicate Key, when you add the duplicate the original will be replaced automatically.

If all you care about is having unique Names and not the order in which they are added/removed all you would need to do is loop over your records and add them to the Map.  Then you could get the values of the Map to obtain your unique records.

```
List<Account> aList1=new List<Account>([select Id,Name from account where Name LIKE '%Falcon%']);
Map<String,Account> aMap=new Map<String,Account>();
for(Account a:aList1)
{
    aMap.put(a.Name,a); //<-- At this point uniqueness is guaranteed.
}

List<Contact> uniqueContacts = aMap.values()// <-- Get unique Contact records.
```